# jQuery Ajax is not working (even simplest action)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently having this code:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e)
{
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
  {
    $.get( "database/control.json", function( order )
    {
        alert(order);
    });
  }
}
```

When I press Enter Key, the browser do nothing, the console doesn't even report any kind of error or anything else. And I don't know how can I solve this. Please help :) Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `e.keyCode` is not equal to 13. Have you added a `console.log()` call to check?

Comment: ...or better yet, used the fully-featured debugger built into your browser?

Comment: I check all informations and still cannot find a way to fix this problem. :(

Comment: Maybe the get simply doesn't return because of the network. Use the debugger to put breakpoints and look at the execution, or use some `console.log` to see what's executed.

Comment: I'm using Prepros, all of my work is local right now

Answer (score 1):

The get is failing ^^

```js
window.onkeydown = function(e)
{
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
  {
  console.log("detected");
    $.get( "database/control.json", function( order )
    {
  console.log("mh");
        alert(order);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Click on the white screen of the snippet before trying to press enter or you wont see it working

Answer (score 0):

There's a few possible problems:

1. Have you included jQuery? You need a `script` tag somewhere that looks like:

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Does your file `database/control.json` exist?

Rather than using `alert` to debug, I encourage you to use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log). This will send messages to your browser's built-in debugger console (in Chrome, you can open it with F12). It will show you error messages, and tell you what part isn't working. There's a good chance that either jQuery or your file isn't being found.

For instance:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('Enter callback is executing.');
    $.get( "database/control.json", function( order ) {
        alert(order);
    });
  }
}
```